# Проблема с запуском программы в Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 c Windows Form

Tags: visual-c++

**Приветствую всех. Я только начал изучать программирование.**

У меня возникает проблема с запуском Windows Forms в Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express. Созданный проект назначен запускаемым. Однако по завершении компиляции появляется сообщение об ошибке в котором сообщается об отсутствии exe файла. Кто может помочь, Пожалуйста помогите.

**Текст ошибки:**

Не удаётся запустить программу "E:\C++\Test1\Debug\Test1.exe" Не удаётся найти указанный файл.

UPD: (перенесено из комментария)
При сборке проекта возникает следующее сообщение:

```
1>------ Построение начато: проект: Test1, Конфигурация: Debug Win32 ------ 
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1123: сбой при преобразовании в COFF: файл недопустим или поврежден 
========== Построение: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========
```

Comment: Может, его и правда нет?

Comment: А компиляция без ошибок проходит?

Comment: Происходит.
В окне компиляции высвечивает:
1>------ Построение начато: проект: Test1, Конфигурация: Debug Win32 ------
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1123: сбой при преобразовании в COFF: файл недопустим или поврежден
========== Построение: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========

Comment: ну как это проходит. Вот у вас ошибка линковки. В результате файл exe просто не создался. См. про ошибку линковки: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/7dz62kfh.aspx

Comment: Да, система личных сообщений вроде бы есть. Но я ей никогда не пользовался.

Comment: Спасибо но т.к. у меня не Visual C++ 2010 Express у меня отсутствуют некоторые параметры в настройках и в результате я не могу использовать все функции.